# Google ad service ends the build with an error

Tags: android, admob

I tried in the past to integrate Google AdMob in my application, and it worked. Now, when I try to rebuild the code, it ends up with an error I don't surely know what is it all about.

I wanted an implementation of a Banner Ad, but it ended up showing this in the build output section: 
**Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:10:5-34:19 to override.
**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fully move to AndroidX.
The new Google AdMob libraries are all for AndroidX, not for support libraries prior 28.0.0.

Comment: How can I do this? Is it a gradle.properties thing? Or what else? Though I opted for androidx. artifacts at the beginning of the app. I don't really know. Please help. :)

Comment: With Android Studio 3.2 and higher, you can migrate an existing project to AndroidX by selecting Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX from the menu bar.